# KeepAlive On stateless widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to add Keep alive on my stateless widget gridview and mixindg cannot be used on stateless widget and when I try to add Keep alive or AlwaysKeepAlive widget it gives following assertion::

The following assertion was thrown while applying parent data.:
Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.

The ParentDataWidget KeepAlive(keepAlive: true) wants to apply ParentData of type KeepAliveParentDataMixin to a RenderObject, which has been set up to accept ParentData of incompatible type ParentData.

Usually, this means that the KeepAlive widget has the wrong ancestor RenderObjectWidget. Typically, KeepAlive widgets are placed directly inside SliverWithKeepAliveWidget widgets.
The offending KeepAlive is currently placed inside a Semantics widget.

any help woud be appriciated

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Responsive.init(context);
    return KeepAlive(
      keepAlive: true,
      child: Obx(() {
        return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
              title: Text(
                contorller.cateid != null
                    ? contorller.cateid!.cateName
                    : 'All products',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
              ),
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              elevation: 0,
              actions: [
                Visibility(
                  child: IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        contorller.showOrHideSearchWidget(true);
                      },
                      icon: Icon(Icons.search)),
                  visible: contorller.isSearchWidget.isFalse,
                )
              ],
            ),

        // appBar: AppBar(
        //   title: Text(contorller.cateid != null
        //       ? contorller.cateid!.cateName
        //       : 'All products'),
        // ),
        body: contorller.isloading.value
            ? Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              )
            : Column(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    height: Responsive.safeBlockVerticalWAB * 2,
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: GridView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      primary: false,
                      // physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                          crossAxisCount: 2, childAspectRatio: .83
                          // childAspectRatio: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width /
                          //     (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1.01),
                          ),
                      itemCount: contorller.productlisrt.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () => Get.to(() => ItemDetails(
                              product: contorller.productlisrt[index])),
                          child: Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                            children: [
                              Stack(
                                children: [
                                  Container(
                                    margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                        horizontal: 10),
                                    child: ClipRRect(
                                      borderRadius:
                                          BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                                      child: Image.network(
                                        '$mainurl/${contorller.productlisrt[index].image}',
                                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Obx(() {
                                    return Positioned(
                                      right:
                                          -Responsive.safeBlockHorizontal *
                                              1,
                                      bottom:
                                          Responsive.safeBlockHorizontal,
                                      child: RawMaterialButton(
                                        onPressed: () {
                                          _favoriteController.toggle(
                                              contorller
                                                  .productlisrt[index]);
                                        },
                                        fillColor: Colors.white,
                                        shape: CircleBorder(),
                                        elevation: 4.0,
                                        child: Padding(
                                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                                          child: _favoriteController
                                                  .hasProduct(contorller
                                                      .productlisrt[index])
                                              ? Icon(
                                                  Icons
                                                      .favorite, // : Icons.favorite_border,
                                                  color: Colors.red,
                                                  size: 17,
                                                )
                                              : Icon(
                                                  Icons.favorite_border,
                                                  color: Colors.red,
                                                  size: 17,
                                                ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    );
                                  })
                                ],
                              ),
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                    left: 10, top: 8.0),
                                child: Text(
                                  contorller.productlisrt[index].itemName,
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 12.0,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                    left: 20, top: 4.0),
                                child: Text(
                                  contorller.productlisrt[index].itemDesc,
                                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 10.0,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                      color: Colors.grey),
                                  maxLines: 1,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ));
  }),
);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure the problem is you’re trying to use `keepAlive` on a stateless widget.

There’s no state *to* “keep alive” on a stateless widget, hence it won’t work. You should, however, be able to use it on a stateful widget.

That’s just my gut feeling!